# TypeError: "property" is read-only

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, runtime-error, typeerror

I updated angular from 8 to 12 and in many places in the project there was an error in the console: TypeError: "property_name" is read-only.

Here is one example of an object with an error:

```
export interface ObjectName {
    index: number;
    name: string;
    widgets: ArrayType[];
}
```

And here is the code where the error occurs:

```
ngOnChanges(): void {
        this.Areas = this.areas
        .map(area => {
            area.index = 10; // ERROR "index" is read-only
            switch (area.name) {
                case '1': area.index = 0; break;
                case '2': area.index = 1; break;
                case '3': area.index = 2; break;
            }

            return area;
        })
        .sort((a, b) => (a.index - b.index));
    }
```

And now there are a lot of such places in the project, I don't understand how to fix it.
I've tried changing the interface to a class, but everything is the same.
Here is my tsconfig.json, but I read about its various settings, it seems there is nothing there that could help me.

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "module": "es2020",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
        "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
    }
}
```

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5d30.png)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to return a new object (re-assign). Something like this will work:

```
.map(area => {
    let index = 10;
    switch (area.name) {
        case 'header_area': index = 0; break;
        case 'content_area': index = 1; break;
        case 'footer_area': index = 2; break;
    }

    return {...area, index};
})
```

The spread-operator `...` will assign the content of `area` to a new object and overwrite `index` with a new value. Extra: `index: index` is redundant, but if the local variable has a different name, you'd need to do e.g. `index: newIndex`.

Comment: Granted using `map` in the way the OP is using `map` doesn't make any sense, but why do they have to copy the object? Is that an Angular thing?

Comment: (Side note: `...` isn't an operator, operators can't do what rest and spread do. `...` is primary syntax. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this not the angular thing , its the basic javascript thing

Comment: @KumailHussain - You're not reading my comment above correctly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, yes, technically `...` is just syntax, but it's commonly referred to as `spread operator`. For the answer: Well, I don't really know, why OP is having the readonly error (e.g. if something gets frozen), but this would get past that.

Comment: @GunnarB i think this is not the solution, the guy has just posted a sample and the question specifically says that  while he migrated to angular 12 he is facing this issue and in many other files, but i am sure its related to some mis configurations in tsconfig.json

Comment: This will probably work as a workaround, but this doesn't answer why, or solve the fact that `index` appears to be read-only. Nor do I think the question contains the details required to answer that...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Considering the edit on OPs question (the 'solution'), yes, the array he tries to iterate is potentially frozen. NGRX is an angular framework for state management insprired by redux and typically the state would always be altered by replacing it (and this is meant to only happen in on specific 'reducer' per part of the state).

Comment: @GunnarB. [As I suspected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69344077/typeerror-property-is-read-only/69344591?noredirect=1#comment122563743_69344077), and it makes sense it's a state management thing separate from Angular tiself. Thanks for letting me know!